# Transmission is not downloading any magnet links!

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, torrent-client

[image: It is always stuck here]

Transmission can't download any magnet links! I tried many torrent websites but seems the problem is with transmission! Whenever I try to download a magnet link it is always stuck on the shown window forever and I have to download a .torrent file to make it download.

Comment: How strange. I *just* used a magnet link successfully using stock Ubuntu 17.10. I used CTRL+U (Open URL) instead of CTRL+O (Open). Paste the magnet link into the URL field.

Comment: I would assume the issue is with the "none" in the 1st option box. No filename... nothing to save. Magnet links are handled by the browser.  You might have a problem there where it does not send over the file name

Comment: it's working with Transmission **QT** version
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kahqi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kahqi.png)

Comment: @user535733 Thanks! That got it running for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Transmission 2.92-3ubuntu2.

The browser handles the magnet link and opens Transmission, but Transmission cannot see the torrent file. Pasting the URL of magnet link didn't work for me but installing the QT version did.

First remove transmission-gtk and then install transmission-qt

```
sudo apt remove transmission-gtk
sudo apt install transmission-qt
```

Everything working like a charm now, no need to paste URL just click on the magnet link to open Transmission and start downloading

Comment: Actually if you selected download location and hit download. It will download.

Comment: I believe you are right @EbramShehata. Event though I couldn't see the torrent file once Transmission was opened, hitting the open button actually started downloading & showing other meta for the torrent